# Controlling a BenQ projector in software - Crestron protocol

Tags: controls, projector

I have a BENQ projector that I need to control in software. It supports the Crestron protocol. I'm working in C#.

Is the Crestron protocol known?

Is there an API or SDK?

Are there samples anywhere for control a projector?

Comment: you can control it using Crestron code you can get the module from Crestron, if you register

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After many days of digging and arguing with BENQ technical support 
the only conclusion is that the protocol is propriety and they will not disclose it.
New firmware for this projector support PJLINK so I am dropping this line of development.

Answer (score 3):

Crestron is not a protocol but a control system based on proprietary hardware and software.  A Crestron module is a bit like a programming library - it can implement a protocol in Crestron's proprietary SIMPL Windows language.  Their tools are only available to dealers and certified Crestron programmers and they don't give them out to anyone who registers on their website.

It appears to be a serial controlled device - 115200,N-8-1.  On the Mini-Din connector, pin 7 is Tx (to a DB9 pin 2), pin 1 is Rx (to pin 3) and pin 4 is Ground (to pin 5).  Here's an image, but the pinout notes on this page differ:  http://business.virgin.net/tom.baldwin/pinout-8minidin.html

Here are some of the commands (each terminated with \x0D):

*pow=on#
*pow=off#

*sour=RGB#
(YPbr, dvid, hdmi, vid, svid)

*asp=4:3#
(16:9, AUTO, REAL)

*mute=on#
*mute=off#

*vol=+#
*vol=-#

*menu#
*up#
*down#
*left#
*right#
*enter#

Answer (score 2):

BenQ now has a file titled [BenQ RS232 Commands](ftp://downloads.benq.net/projector/manuals/RS_Commands_Generic_082613.pdf) available for download. It lists cable pinout and a whole bunch of RS-232 commands.  The command syntax is one I've not seen before, perhaps it is Crestron-compatible.  But if you're writing your own software, this file should be all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Does this not work?

```
REM batch file
REM ASCII CR*pow=on#CR
MODE COM1:115200,N,8,1
ECHO ^x0D^x2A^x70^x6F^x77^x3D^x6F^x6E^x23^x0D > COM1

REM ASCII CR*pow=off#CR
MODE COM1:115200,N,8,1
ECHO ^x0D^x2A^x70^x6F^x77^x3D^x6F^x66^x66^x23^x0D > COM1
```